# Quick Questions about NodeLists (Perl)

Tags: xml, perl, nodelist

I have a NodeList and I would like to

1. Find out if the size is equal to 1

2.Take print the contents of the node if the list is equal to 1

```
 my @dbRefs     = $context->findnodes('.//u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id', $entry);
 if(@dbRefs == 1){
    print @dbRefs->get_node(1), "\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [`findnodes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode)

> `@nodes = $node->findnodes( $xpath_expression );`
>
> `findnodes` evaluates the xpath expression (XPath 1.0) on the current node and returns the resulting node set as an array. In scalar context, returns an [`XML::LibXML::NodeList`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNodeList) object.

Since you're just pulling an array, to get the first element just use `$dbRefs[0]`

```
my @dbRefs = $context->findnodes('.//u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id', $entry);
if (@dbRefs == 1){
    print $dbRefs[0], "\n";
}
```

Comment: or `my ($dbRef) = $context->findnodes(...); if ($dbRef) { print $dbRef, "\n"; }`

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't cover the OP's requirement to specifically only print if the *"size is equal to 1"*.

Comment: I bet it can't find more than one, in which case it is the same. But if it can find more than one, then yeah it's not quite the same.

Comment: It can, but only knew that based off earlier questions: [`Extracting and Storing XML Data with libXML/XPath`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23852176/1733163)

Answer (score 0):

The `findnodes` method returns *either* a list of node objects in list context, which is how you have it, *or* a single `XML::LibXML::NodeList` object in scalar context.

How you process the result depends on what sort of value you have.

In list context you can write

```
my @dbRefs = $context->findnodes('.//u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id', $entry);

if (@dbRefs == 1) {
  print $dbRefs[0], "\n";
}
```

or, using scalar context

```
my $dbRefs = $context->findnodes('.//u:dbReference[@type="EC"]/@id', $entry);

if ($dbRefs->size == 1) {
  print $dbRefs->get_node(1), "\n";
}
```